# How do I add a private IP output for an instance in GCP using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have this output defined in my TF code in `outputs.tf`:

```
output "ip" {
  value = google_compute_address.vm_private_ip.address
}
```

This is the code I use to create the instance in `main.tf`:

```
// Launch an MS SQL Server into GCP
// Configure the Google Cloud provider
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("mycreds.json")
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
}

// Terraform plugin for creating random ids
resource "random_id" "instance_id" {
 byte_length = 8
}

// A single Compute Engine instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = var.instance_name
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.zone
  tags         = [var.instance_name, var.env_name]
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
    size =  var.boot_disk_size
    image = data.google_compute_image.sqlserverimage.self_link
    }

    }

  network_interface {
  subnetwork = var.subnetwork
  subnetwork_project = var.subnetwork_project
 }
}

data "google_compute_image" "sqlserverimage" {
  family  = var.image_family
  project = var.project
}

// Create additional disks
resource "google_compute_disk" "datadisk" {
  name  = var.data_disk_name
  type  = var.data_disk_type
  size  = var.data_disk_size
  zone  = var.zone
  image = data.google_compute_image.sqlserverimage.self_link
  labels = {
    environment = "dev"
    asv = "mycompanytools"
    ownercontact = "myuser"
  }
  physical_block_size_bytes = 4096
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "backupdisk" {
  name  = var.backup_disk_name
  type  = var.backup_disk_type
  size  = var.backup_disk_size
  zone  = var.zone
  image = data.google_compute_image.sqlserverimage.self_link
  labels = {
    environment = "dev"
    asv = "mycompanytools"
    ownercontact = "myuser"
  }
  physical_block_size_bytes = 4096
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "logdisk" {
  name  = var.log_disk_name
  type  = var.log_disk_type
  size  = var.log_disk_size
  zone  = var.zone
  image = data.google_compute_image.sqlserverimage.self_link
  labels = {
    environment = "dev"
    asv = "mycompanytools"
    ownercontact = "myuser"
  }
  physical_block_size_bytes = 4096
}

// Attach additional disks
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "datadiskattach" {
  disk = google_compute_disk.datadisk.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.default.id
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "backupdiskattach" {
  disk = google_compute_disk.backupdisk.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.default.id
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "logdiskattach" {
  disk = google_compute_disk.logdisk.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.default.id
}
```

But when I run a `terraform plan` I get this error:

```
terraform plan

Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on outputs.tf line 2, in output "ip":
   2:   value = google_compute_address.vm_private_ip.address

A managed resource "google_compute_address" "vm_private_ip" has not been
declared in the root module.
```

The private IP will not be known until the instance is created. How do I get an output to show the private IP? I do not want to assign an IP to the instance, I just want to know what IP it has once it's created.

Comment: Can you edit the code in your question so that it forms a [mcve] please? Right now it just looks like you haven't addressed your `google_compute_address` resource as `vm_private_ip` but it's impossible to tell exactly where you've gone wrong from the current code.

Comment: Ok sure, I'll add that now.

Comment: Ok I've just updated the OP with my original code. Thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't include a `google_compute_address` resource which explains the error. Did you want to add one and haven't done so? Or do you just want the IP address of the `google_compute_instance` resource?

Comment: I just want to know the IP address of the instance once it's created. I don't want to give it one.

Answer (score 2):

The below output block will give you the desired output value

```
output "ip" {
  value = google_compute_instance.default.network_interface.0.network_ip
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the default, dynamically assigned IP address of a Google Compute instance created via the `google_compute_instance` resource you can access the `network_interface.0.network_ip` attribute as described in [the resource documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#network_interface.0.network_ip):

> - `network_interface.0.network_ip` - The internal ip address of the instance, either manually or dynamically assigned.

So your output should be:

```
output "ip" {
  value = google_compute_instance.default.network_interface.0.network_ip
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that to my output: ```output "ip" {
  value = network_interface.0.network_ip
}```

But I get this error back:

```terraform plan

Error: Invalid reference

  on outputs.tf line 2, in output "ip":
   2:   value = network_interface.0.network_ip

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.``` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @bluethundr you have exactly missed to provide the resource and it's identifier name